# pdflatex error but nothing in log file

Tags: pdftex, compilation-error

I have a file that exhibits a strange behavior:

```
$ pdflatex --interaction=batchmode myfile.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mod
$ echo $?
1
```

The log file seems to have no error:

```
$ grep error myfile.log
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
```

I also visually checked the log file (3000 lines): can't see anything.
It ends with:

```
Output written on myfile.pdf (98 pages, 3034645 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 1292 PDF objects out of 1440 (max. 8388607)
 1054 compressed objects within 11 object streams
 211 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 402 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I also checked the other generated files: nothing special.
But the pdf output file is generated, and seems ok.

This is annoying, because the build process is embedded in a makefile, and `make` triggers an error each time (because of the non-null return value), although the output file is ok.

**Questions**: what steps can I take now ? What do I have to look for in the log file?

Additional information:

- the file is a 2000-lines beamer file, utf8-encoded. It does not happens with other files, so I suspect something in there...
- pdflatex version: 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)
- OS: ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Try without `--interaction=batchmode`, then TeX will stop at the first error

Comment: !!! Thanks, I feel so stupid.. Did'nt even think about that. You think the question has some value ? Else, I might delete that one.

Comment: No problem ;-) If you got to solve the error by yourself, then I think you can delete it (it's not too common for users to check the exit code of TeX :-). Else you can edit your question with the error message so that we can find out what's happening

Comment: For the future reader: **DO NOT** (as I did...) assume all errors will shows off in the logfile as `! LaTeX Error: (something)` ! In this case, it was a simple `! Missing \right. inserted.`

Comment: Ah, a TeX error :-) They are harder to `grep` for. Usually you can look for `^!` or `^l\.`, but you might get some false positives.

Comment: Often it is just easier to manually look in the log file with less or similar. You see a similar problem with the editors who give a curated view of the log file, they sometimes miss stuff because tye message does not match their filters. One fun test is to enable the feature where errors are prefixed by the file they are coming from (there is a cli option for this). Then the curation filters can't find any errors

Comment: @daleif "`...manually look in the log...`": Yep, true... but with 3000 lines, it ai'nt really easy to spot those errors !

Comment: That is just a matter of experience and how you use say `less`